# Is there a way to find out the appropriate fee when generate tx?

Tags: fee, sidecar

We using sidecar, And we want a fast transaction even if we pay a high fee.

Do you happen to have statistics on the appropriate fees for transfer?

If not, is there a way to know the appropriate fee for runtime in real time?

I know that the sidecar will know the fee for the completed transaction.
But we have to figure out fee at the stage where the transaction is being made.

Answer (score 2):

Sidecar also has a `POST /transaction/fee-estimate` endpoint where you can submit the transaction and get the current fee rate (sans tip). Then you can add a tip to get increased priority.